# SVG not showing on iOS

Tags: css, svg

Image shows fine on Chrome OS X. I also have another SVG (background-image) which is showing, but this one isn't on iOS.

I've read that there are limits for images on iOS devices, but this isn't a particularly big image. [Here are the contents of the SVG](https://gist.github.com/chrisloftus/be19172da1281c299f46), exported from Illustrator. Apache seems to be serving the correct content-type: svg+xml.

I've created a pen here – http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJJWbN

```
<h1><a href="#">Logo</a></h1>

h1 a {
  background: url('http://bogglo-beta.liprock.com/img/logo.svg') 0 0 no-repeat;
  /* background-size: contain; */
  border: solid 1px tomato;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 58px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 180px;
}
```

Here's a screenshot with the image not showing:

[image: iOS Screenshot]

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Can't find any resource, but IMHO, it's due to the fact that your image is a base64 png embedded into an svg. (can repro with any embedded png in svg). This might be a bug in ios, but if your image is really only composed of this png, why don't you pass only the png as a background-image?

Comment: @Kaiido: Do you mean just use a PNG instead of SVG file? What I have is a Photoshop PSD with a logo as a smart object. I want to save that as a SVG so I don't need to save different sizes for retina 2x and 3x, etc. I did `Layer > Smart Objects > Export Contents` which saved the PNG and then opened in Illustrator and saved as an SVG. Is this the wrong way? Thanks for the reply, btw.

Comment: hum yes I think it's the wrong way. I'm not really into those smart objects but I think you need to double click it, then it will open illustrator and there you can save it as an svg. You added a unwanted rasterization step by exporting it to png.

Comment: @Kaiido: When I export paths to Illustrator there is just a blank artboard :-(

Comment: Hmm like I said, I'm no specialist of those, maybe you could try saving it to eps and open it directly in illustrator or ask a question on [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [graphicdesign](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)